Python script in R Markdown
I am using R Markdown and running a python script in it using reticulate. When I am trying to print out some values related to the model then upon knitting the output shows like this:

Even though I am not printing the model details they are still appearing above my desired output values. Anyone who knows why is this happening? Would be a great help if you could help resolving it.

have include = FALSE, echo = FALSE as the chunk options in the chunk that is printing the results.

That made the whole chunk stop printing anything, and obviously I do want to print out the values just don't want the model details above them.

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(reticulate)


# Creating the Random Forest Classifier

RFC = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 63, criterion = 'gini', random_state = 0)
RFC.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Applying k-fold cross validation

accuracies = cross_val_score(estimator = RFC, X = X_train, y = y_train, cv = 10)
print(f"Average Accuracy: {accuracies.mean()*100: .2f}%")
print(f"Standard Deviation of Accuracy: {accuracies.std()*100: .2f}%")


Note that R prints any results by default. That will happen to python chunks too. So you have 2 options. 1)Save the output into a variable so that it is not printed. even though you do not end up using that variable(This is the option proposed by the answer below) 2)Run the model in a different chunk with include = FALSE, echo = FALSE then print the results in a different python chunk.

From the image it looks like that there is a line in your Python code that returns a RandomForestClassifier. If you do not need to reuse the returned object add _= in front of the suspected line. You can also try adding a semicolon ; to the end of the line, if R Markdown behaves like the Jupyter notebook.

Don't think that I have printed that because when I ran it simply as a python script, it was fine. Anyways here is the code: RFC = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 63, criterion = 'gini', random_state = 0)
RFC.fit(X_train, y_train)
Applying k-fold cross validation
accuracies = cross_val_score(estimator = RFC, X = X_train, y = y_train, cv = 10)
print(f"Average Accuracy: {accuracies.mean()*100: .2f}%")
print(f"Standard Deviation of Accuracy: {accuracies.std()*100: .2f}%")

@NamanKumar RFC.fit(X_train, y_train) returns the object itself, and the notebooks (R Markdown or Jupyter) usually print the objects out even if you do not explicitly print them, therefore you need to suppress the output, try changing the line to RFC = RFC.fit(X_train, y_train)

It worked. Thanks a bunch.
